# StepLR Learning Rate Scheduler applying an almost infinitely small decrease and also too early

Tags: python, pytorch, learning-rate

I am using the `StepLR` scheduler with the `Adam` optimizer:

```
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LrMax, weight_decay=decay) # , betas=(args.beta1, args.beta2)
    print(f'Optimizer = {repr(optimizer)}')
    scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.2)
```

The initial learning rate *lr* is set to 0.1. At the end of the first epoch the situation is stable:

```
Train: Epoch 0 Batch=601 totalBatches=601 lr=0.1: Loss=2.5451838970184326 accuracy=0.1875
Train: Epoch 0 Batch=651 totalBatches=651 lr=0.1: Loss=3.527266025543213 accuracy=0.1875
Train: Epoch 0 Batch=656 totalBatches=656 lr=0.1: Loss=2.9547425508499146 accuracy=0.1875
```

But then the clock strikes midnight, we move on to epoch1 and the Learning Rate Scheduler goes bonkers:

```
Train: Epoch 1 Batch=45 totalBatches=701 lr=2.722258935367529e-93: Loss=2.878746271133423 
accuracy=0.25
```

- Why did the learning rate drop by 10^92 ?
- Why did the learning rate change on the first epoch instead of epoch 5?

Comment: Have you find a way to solve this? It looks like the step size is not respected

Comment: No, I gave up on StepLR